# Blender 2.8 Eevee - Linked Collection with Disabled Rendered Visibility Objects are Rendered?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I've been trying to find and answer to this. I have a linked collection containing an object that I've disabled Rendered Visibility.

[image]

[image]

However, whenever this collection is linked into a new scene, the object that has Rendered Visibility toggled off, that object is rendered!
[image]

If I switch to Cycles, the object is not visible, so this seems to be an Eevee issue. How can I link a collection containing an object that I don't want rendered and have it work in Eeveve?

Comment: not sure what your problem is, but that model is awesome. ;)